# New screen-tabs after user signs in

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

In GUI NetBeans I have `JFrame` with a `JTabbedPane`. There are 3 tabs on the top, each one for a different user. Each tab has `JPanel` where user have to enter password. After the password is verified I got rid of the other two tabs by asking tabbed pane to remove other two tabs by a method `remove(), since once the user is signed in other two users tabs are not relevant anymore.

Now I'm left with only one tab, however after a user had signed in I want that user to see new tabs - panels, while removing the previous tabs I don't know how to put this into code since I don't know where I should create the new screen with tabbed pane that will become visible to the user.

I tried to add another JTabbedPane, to a frame alongside the first tabbed pane, and make it not visible until user is verified, while the first tabbed pane is removed, however in a NetBeans design window the new pane is on top of the first one so I cant add components to a new tab pane.

I know Im not doing it in the correct way. Can somebody give me advice on how to code solution for getting new tab screen for the user who has signed in?

Comment: *"I dont know where else to position new JTabbedPane in the structure in a navigator window or where I should design alternative tab screens."* do you know where you should ask a question? (Tip: In among those words above.)

Comment: sorry, I didnt get that.

Comment: You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is the ***question?***

Comment: `I got rid of the other two tabs by asking tabbed pane to remove other two tabs by a method `remove(),` - so why can't you add another tab at the same time using the `addTab(...)` method of the JTabbedPane. If you problem is the IDE then don't use the IDE to built the GUI since the code will not be portable to other IDE's. Instead spend your time learning Java/Swing not the IDE.

Comment: the problem is not adding the tab, it can be done easily, portability and Netbeans are not problem either. I will need to make constant changes to GUI so drop down Design view in NetBeans is suitable for this. Only the problem is where to design the new screens that appears later after users  have signed in.  Do I have to make separate new Swing Frames and when users have signed in the main Frame clear all tabs and add new frames?

Comment: I posted previous comment by mistake. Adding tab, is easy, portability and Netbeans are not problem either.  Because of constant changes to GUI drop down Design view in NetBeans is suitable. Problem is where the new screens that appears after sign in should be coming from.  Do I have to make separate new Swing Frames so after main Frame clear all tabs then creates and adds new frame to the main frame? Is it done in a similar way as one class creates other classes and invoke its method?  Or can the main frame add JPanel from other Swing Frame? I cant find anywhere how this should be done.

Comment: My gut feeling is you want to change your approach, start with a single panel, through which the user logs in, based in their "user permissions", use a `CardLayout` to switch to the appropriate view which contains the tabs that user can see